# creating an desktop application for displaying status of our inputs as a graph

Tags: java, swing, layout, panel

I started a small application to display the graph of my input values. for this i used `Swing` frame and panels on it. my desired output is taking more number of inputs from user and calculate the averages of each group values and display them on a window after clicking the button. for this i taken one frame and two panels. now what is the problem is while i'm adding more and more number of components to my panel it won't allow to extend the size of panel . it extended upto approximately `1366*768` size only. but i have so many components to add to it. i tested with almost all layout managers and finally now using group layout.
   and also i'm not able to add the panel with the graphs after clicking on button in enter code here`is group layout. i used button click event.
        please suggest what to say. my code is as below

**//class main to start the frame**

```
public class Main {

 public static void main(String args[])
{

      Application app=new Application();
}

}
```

**//class Application**

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;


 public class Application extends JFrame {

private MainPanel currentpanel;
public Application()
{
    currentpanel = new MainPanel();     
    setupFrame();
}

private void setupFrame()
{
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(currentpanel);
    //getContentPane().
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    //scrollPane.add(currentpanel);
    //this.setContentPane(scrollPane);

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(1070,831);

}

}


class Pan extends JPanel
{
public Pan()
{
JPanel m= new MainPanel();  
this.add(m);
}
}
```

**//class mainpanel**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.StandardEntityCollection;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;
private JTextField textField_9;
private JTextField textField_10;
private JTextField textField_11;
private JTextField textField_12;
private JTextField textField_13;
private JTextField textField_14;
private JTextField textField_15;
private JTextField textField_16;
private JTextField textField_17;
private JTextField textField_18;
private JTextField textField_19;
private JScrollPane scrollPane_1;
private int a;
private boolean f;
public MainPanel()
{

    setupPanel();

}
private void setupPanel()
{
    setBackground(new Color(138, 43, 226));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("statement 1");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("statement 2");
    lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("statement 3");
    lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("statement 4");
    lblNewLabel_4.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("statement 5");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));


    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setColumns(10);

    textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_6.setColumns(10);

    textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setColumns(10);

    textField_8 = new JTextField();
    textField_8.setColumns(10);

    textField_9 = new JTextField();
    textField_9.setColumns(10);

    textField_10 = new JTextField();
    textField_10.setColumns(10);

    textField_11 = new JTextField();
    textField_11.setColumns(10);

    textField_12 = new JTextField();
    textField_12.setColumns(10);

    textField_13 = new JTextField();
    textField_13.setColumns(10);

    textField_14 = new JTextField();
    textField_14.setColumns(10);

    textField_15 = new JTextField();
    textField_15.setColumns(10);

    textField_16 = new JTextField();
    textField_16.setColumns(10);

    textField_17 = new JTextField();
    textField_17.setColumns(10);

    textField_18 = new JTextField();
    textField_18.setColumns(10);

    textField_19 = new JTextField();
    textField_19.setColumns(10);

    scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();

    JPanel panel = new GraphPanel();
    final MyChart bar=new MyChart();


    JButton btnCheckTheStatus = new JButton("Check the Status");
    btnCheckTheStatus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(textField.getText()!=null)
                a=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            if(a!=0)
            {
                bar.prepareChart(a);
            }
            f=true;         

        }
    });
    btnCheckTheStatus.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(218)
                        .addComponent(scrollPane_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 843, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(60)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(48)
                                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(68)
                                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(66)
                                        .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(48)
                                        .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(68)
                                        .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(66)
                                        .addComponent(textField_6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(textField_7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(48)
                                        .addComponent(textField_8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(68)
                                        .addComponent(textField_9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(66)
                                        .addComponent(textField_10, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(textField_11, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(48)
                                        .addComponent(textField_12, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(68)
                                        .addComponent(textField_13, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(66)
                                        .addComponent(textField_14, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(textField_15, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(48)
                                        .addComponent(textField_16, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(68)
                                        .addComponent(textField_17, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(66)
                                        .addComponent(textField_18, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(textField_19, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                        .addGap(56)
                        .addComponent(btnCheckTheStatus)))
                .addContainerGap(152, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47)
                .addComponent(scrollPane_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(36)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(2)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(49)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(43)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_10, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_11, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(44)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_12, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_13, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_14, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_15, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(55)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_16, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_17, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_18, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField_19, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnCheckTheStatus)))
                .addGap(31)
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 316, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    setLayout(groupLayout);
}
}




class GraphPanel extends JPanel{
JScrollPane scrollPane;
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon("BarChart.png");
ImageIcon icon1= new ImageIcon("BarChart.png");

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
            {

                g.drawImage(icon.getImage(),10, 10, 300, 200,   null);
                g.drawImage(icon1.getImage(),320, 10, 300, 200, null);
            }



}


class MyChart
{
private  int a;
private int b;
private int c;
private int d;
private int e;
public void prepareChart(int a){
this.a=a;
b=a+a;
c=a;
d=b;
e=a+b;

DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

dataset.setValue(a, "Marks", "1");
 dataset.setValue(b, "Marks", "2");
 dataset.setValue(c, "Marks", "3");
 dataset.setValue(d, "Marks", "4");
dataset.setValue(e, "Marks", "5");

 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart
 ("Status of your thoughts","Feild", "Status", dataset, 
  PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,true, false);
 chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
 chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue); 
 CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
 p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.pink); 
ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("Bar Chart",chart);
 frame1.setVisible(true);
 frame1.setSize(400,350);

  try{
  final ChartRenderingInfo info = new  ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
  final File file1=new File("BarChart.png");
  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400,info);
  //System.out.println("image created");
}catch(Exception e)
 {
  System.out.println("image can not be created");

 }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you not to use `GroupLayout` is really hard, instead of you can try to use [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), it's simplier.

To embed `JFreeChart` to your `JPanel` use `ChartPanel`.

Use `pack();` method instead of `setSize()` to your `JFrame`.

I don't recommend you to use `new ImageIcon("BarChart.png")`, in that case you can have problems with path to file. Add your "BarChart.png" to resources of project and get them with help of `URL` like next: `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("BarChart.png"))`.

I've changed your code, examine that:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.StandardEntityCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

public class Example extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String... s){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new Example());
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JScrollPane pane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;
    private JTextField textField_12;
    private JTextField textField_13;
    private JTextField textField_14;
    private JTextField textField_15;
    private JTextField textField_16;
    private JTextField textField_17;
    private JTextField textField_18;
    private JTextField textField_19;
    private int a;
    private boolean f;

    public Example() {
        setupPanel();
    }

    private JTextField createField(){
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        return textField;
    }

    private void setupPanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(138, 43, 226));
        textField = createField();
        textField_1 = createField();
        textField_2 =createField();
        textField_3 = createField();
        textField_4 = createField();
        textField_5 =createField();
        textField_6 = createField();
        textField_7 = createField();
        textField_8 = createField();
        textField_9 = createField();
        textField_10 = createField();
        textField_11 = createField();
        textField_12 = createField();
        textField_13 = createField();
        textField_14 = createField();
        textField_15 = createField();
        textField_16 = createField();
        textField_17 = createField();
        textField_18 = createField();
        textField_19 = createField();

        JPanel panel = new GraphPanel();
        final MyChart bar = new MyChart();

        JButton btnCheckTheStatus = new JButton("Check the Status");
        btnCheckTheStatus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (textField.getText() != null)
                    a = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                if (a != 0) {
                    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(bar.prepareChart(a));
                    pane.setViewportView(chartPanel);
                    Example.this.revalidate();
                }
                f = true;

            }
        });
        btnCheckTheStatus.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
            JLabel l = new JLabel("statement "+i);
            l.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.PLAIN, 16));
            add(l,c);
            c.gridy ++;
        }
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_1,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_2,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_3,c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        add(textField_4,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_5,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_6,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_7,c);

        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        add(textField_8,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_9,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_10,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_11,c);

        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridx = 1;
        add(textField_12,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_13,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_14,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_15,c);

        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridx = 1;
        add(textField_16,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_17,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_18,c);
        c.gridx ++;
        add(textField_19,c);

        c.gridx++;
        add(btnCheckTheStatus,c);

        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 6;
        add(panel,c);

        pane = new JScrollPane();
        c.gridx = 6;
        c.gridheight = 7;
        c.ipady= 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(pane,c);
    }

    class GraphPanel extends JPanel {
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("BarChart.png");
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("BarChart.png"));

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 10, 10, 300, 200, null);
            g.drawImage(icon1.getImage(), 320, 10, 300, 200, null);
        }

        @Override
        @Transient
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(650,200);
        }

    }

    class MyChart {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;
        private int d;
        private int e;

        public JFreeChart prepareChart(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            b = a + a;
            c = a;
            d = b;
            e = a + b;

            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

            dataset.setValue(a, "Marks", "1");
            dataset.setValue(b, "Marks", "2");
            dataset.setValue(c, "Marks", "3");
            dataset.setValue(d, "Marks", "4");
            dataset.setValue(e, "Marks", "5");

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    "Status of your thoughts", "Feild", "Status", dataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
            chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue);
            CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
            p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.pink);
            try {
                final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(
                        new StandardEntityCollection());
                final File file1 = new File("BarChart.png");
                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("image can not be created");

            }
            return chart;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you rather use JavaFX for this, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html
and specifically for charts: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm